# $.ajax statusCode handlers called after promise object returns complete

Tags: ajax, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to write some qunit unit tests for my knockout view models and I've run into an interesting issue.

In my view model I have the following function:

```
    Get = function (id) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: API + "/" + id,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: Timeout,
            statusCode: {
                200: GetOneSuccess,
                404: ItemNotFound
            },
            error: function () {
                //Item(null);
            }
        });
    },
```

Then in my unit test I have this:

```
vm.Get(vm.Item().Id()).then(function () {                    
   ok(false, "Failure!");
},function () {
   equal(vm.Item(), null, "Item was removed");
   start();
});
```

ItemNotFound is as follows:

```
    ItemNotFound = function () {
        Item(null);
    }
```

This is pretty straight forward, if the API controller returns "NotFound (Error 404)" set the Item to null.  I am finding that my test if failing because when "then" is called the ItemNotFound function has not completed yet.

If I add a timeout to my unit test, it works:

```
            vm.Get(vm.Item().Id()).then(function () {                    
                    ok(false, "Failure!");
            },function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        equal(vm.Item(), null, "Item was removed");
                        start();
                    }, 2000);
            });
```

Anyone have any thoughts?  Should I just not bother with the statusCodes and just handle all error types in the error handler?  Doesn't seem as elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Error handlers are fired first before the status code functions are fired. The "then" function takes a "success callback" and an "error callback". So in essence, your error (fail) is firing before the statuscode "notfound" fires.

When you are setting up a timeout, the function returns immediately, fires your status code and then based on your set timeout, fires that specific code.

If you still want the code structure you have then here is how I would do it. Your GET function should return a Deffered promise object that encapsulates the actual ajax call and don't specify a success or error handler and call your success or error functions first from your statusCode.

I have created a fiddle for the same

http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/BWA9D/15/

```
var data = {
    json: $.toJSON({
        text: 'some text',
        array: [1, 2, 'three'],
        object: {
            par1: 'another text',
            par2: [3, 2, 'one'],
            par3: {}
        }
    })
}


var callEcho = function(url) {
    return $.Deferred(function(def){
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        statusCode: {
            200: function(data,xhr){
                GetOneSuccess();
                def.resolve(data);
            },
            404: function(xhr){
                ItemNotFound();
                def.reject();
            }
        }
    });    
}).promise();

};

function GetOneSuccess(){
    alert('Get One success Called');
}

function ItemNotFound(){
    alert('Item Not Found Called');
}

var testFunc = function(url){
    var js = callEcho(url);
    js.done(function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data) + ' done function called');
    });

    js.fail(function(){
        alert('fail function called.');
    });
}

//fire the success
testFunc("/echo/json/" );

//fire the fail
testFunc("/echo/jso/");
```